# Can't upload file "Undefined index: imageData" with Angular and PHP

Tags: php, angular

I need to upload file with PrimeNG and found data in FormData when `console.log` but PHP response `Undefined index: imageData`

My HTML Code :

```
<p-fileUpload name="imageData" id="imageData" customUpload="true" mode="basic" (onSelect)="onFileSelected($event)" (uploadHandler)="onUpload()"></p-fileUpload>
```

TS Code :

```
selectFile: File;


onFileSelected(event) {
    this.selectFile = event.files[0];
  }


onUpload() {
    const myheaders = { 'Content-type': 'undefined' };
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('imageData', this.selectFile, this.selectFile.name);
    console.log(formData.getAll('imageData'));
    this.http
      .post<any>('http://localhost/project/api/upload.php', formData, {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
        headers: myheaders
      })
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {}
      );
}
```

when `console.log(formData.getAll('imageData'));` i get :

[image]

when upload I get `Undefined index: imageData`

PHP Code :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');

include('./db_connect.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $myfile = json_decode($content, true);

    $imageData = json_encode($_FILES['imageData']);

    echo $imageData;
    
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

and I try to send data with POSTMAN PHP response is :

[image]